# How to apply slideToggle in two elements within dynamically genereted div(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some div(s) which are dynamically generated by PHP. There are two section(span,class applied) in every div. There is a button for the first section(in every div). Which toggles the first section . In the first section there is a button to toggle second section.

Note:First and Second section is the child of the Parent div. But its not working properly. After generating some DIVs dynamically , second toggle is not working on the other divs except the Last one. Here is the Code:

**JQuery:**

/////////////// section 1 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
$(function(){

           $('.section1').hide();
           $('.section2').hide();

    $('.section1_toggle').click(function(){
             $(this).parents('div').find('.section1').each(function(){
                                $(this).slideToggle();               
                                                 });
                                             });           
           });
/////////////// section 2 \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

$(function(){
    $('.section2_toggle').click(function(){
             $(this).parents('div').find('.section2').each(function(){
                                $(this).slideToggle();
                                                 });
                                             });

           });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">

  <span>
     <input type="button" name="" class="section1_toggle" id=""/>
  </span>



  <span class="section1">
     -------some text---------
     <input type="button" name="" class="section2_toggle" id=""/>
  </span>



  <span class="section2">
   -------some text---------

  </span>
```

Please help to work this code as I expected.

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle

Comment: Is the toggle working for normal div which is not created dynamically??

Comment: In a single Div, then its OK. But in this situation its working(last toggle) on last div. In the other divs first sections are working properly. But not working on second section , that is: clicking on the button contained by the fist section not toggling the second section.

Comment: @Chinmoy may be you should try with `.closest()` instead of `.parent()`

Comment: Is the situation improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if these 
span class="section" are generated dynamically, you need to attach click event to static parent, passing span as secont parameter:

```
$('.main').on('click', 'span.section1', function() {

// code here

});
```

Comment: Yes, Dynamically generated by PHP. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to delegate the click event to the closest static parent:

so instead of doing for every btn, you can simply do this.

```
$(function(){

   $('.section1').hide();
   $('.section2').hide();

   $('.main').on('click', '[class$="toggle"]', function(){
       $(this).closest('div').find('[class^="section"]').each(function(){
          $(this).slideToggle();
       });
   });

});
```

this would do for all the elems whose class name starts(`^`) with *section*, it loops through it and `slidetoggle` the current elem.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are dynamically added you can use event delegation:

> The majority of browser events bubble, or propagate, from the deepest,
>   innermost element (the event target) in the document where they occur
>   all the way up to the body and the document element. In Internet
>   Explorer 8 and lower, a few events such as change and submit do not
>   natively bubble but jQuery patches these to bubble and create
>   consistent cross-browser behavior.
>
> If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as
>   direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event
>   occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the
>   element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.
>
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

You can use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Code:

```
$(function () {

    $('.section1').hide();
    $('.section2').hide();

    $('body').on('click', '.section1_toggle', function () {
        $(this).parents('div').find('.section1').each(function () {
            $(this).slideToggle();
        });
    });

    $('body').on('click', '.section2_toggle', function () {
        $(this).parents('div').find('.section2').each(function () {
            $(this).slideToggle();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: The click hanlder is fired, what problem are you facing?

Comment: First DIV(
  First Slide Works
  Second Slide not working)
Second Div(
  First Slide Works
  Second Slide Works)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is dynamically generated you should have to use `.live()` in jQuery. But `.live()` is a deprecated function. so you can use `.on()` which applies your actions to a lively(dynamically) created elements.

```
$('.section2').on('click','.section2',function(){

     //your code goes here

})
```

Answer (score 0):

A little suggestion. You should wrap `-------some text---------` in a `span` element, like this:

```
<span class="section1">
     <span>-------some text---------</span>
     <input type="button" name="" class="section2_toggle" id=""/>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @Super Cool Handsome G for your suggestion. I'll follow that.